# How to determine the "z-index of a shadow"

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, z-index, shadow

I'm sorry for the title, can not synthesize differently the issue. Here's the problem:
[image: Wrong one]
[image: Right one]

In my UICollectionView have some cells that want to put a shadow, they are arranged very close to each other which makes the shadow of each one reach the neighbor (first image), when what I want, is that it only reaches the background (second image).

**What I've thought or tried:**

1. I can not put a view behind the cells, adding their frames to it, and apply shadow in this view because the cells has dynamic movement (UIDynamics CollectionView Layout).
2. I tried, in the subclass of UICollectionViewLayout, put all these cells in the same z-index. Did not work. Find out why:

> [var **zIndex:** Int](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes/zIndex)
>
> (...) Items with the same value have an *undetermined
> order*.

I would like some help with my problem, please. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the TheEye response, I decided to implement **`UIDecorationViews`**. All great now.

```
// MARK: At UICollectionViewCustomLayout:

public override init() {
    super.init()
    // Register the NIB of the view that will hold the shadows:
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "Shadow", bundle: nil)
    self.registerNib(nib, forDecorationViewOfKind: "shadow")
}

public override func layoutAttributesForDecorationViewOfKind(elementKind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    let layoutAtt: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forDecorationViewOfKind: "shadow", withIndexPath: indexPath)
    layoutAtt.frame = (layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.frame)!
    layoutAtt.zIndex = -1
    return layoutAtt
    }

public override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    var atts = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
    let numberOfItems:Int = (self.collectionView?.numberOfItemsInSection(0))!
    for index in 0..<numberOfItems {
        let layoutItem = layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: index, inSection: 0))!
        let frameItem = layoutItem.frame
        if CGRectIntersectsRect(frameItem, rect) {
            atts.append(layoutAttributesForDecorationViewOfKind("shadow", atIndexPath: NSIndexPath(forItem: index, inSection: 0))!)
            atts.append(layoutItem)
        }
    }
    return atts
}

// MARK: At the Nib Class File:

// Here I created a additional view to append the shadow. 
// Thats because awakeFromNib() is called before the UICollectionViewCustomLayout 
// have a chance to layout it, but I want to make 
// use of shadowPath to gain performance, thats why 
// I make use of the additional UIView with autolayout stuffs.

@IBOutlet weak var shadowView: UIView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    shadowView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0)
    shadowView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor
    shadowView.layer.shadowRadius = 3
    shadowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    let shadowFrame: CGRect = shadowView.layer.bounds
    let shadowPath: CGPathRef = UIBezierPath(rect: shadowFrame).CGPath
    shadowView.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath
    shadowView.clipsToBounds = false
    self.clipsToBounds = false
}
```

Comment: Good work - but I would change the `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect` function to check for the kind of decoration view and return the shadow for the "shadow" type - it's more general and will also work when you add more decoration views.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to define the shadows as supplementary views, aligned with their respective cells, and give them a lower z order than the cells.